# DRM support in Firefox OS

Tags: video, firefox-os, drm

What DRM formats does Firefox OS support?

I found EME https://hsivonen.fi/eme/, but it isn't helpful.

I just want to play videos on fxos from dev point of view.

- Mozilla does not share any specification to DRM support at all.
- I've asked at Mozilla IRC (#fxos) more than five times during last week and nobody replied.
- Mozilla has disabled account creation (DOS attack) for at least one week, so could not ask there either.

Comment: FirefoxOS use open formats for video. Not sure what you're asking about DRM?

Comment: Loïc Faure-Lacroix: I'm doing research what can be done on different smartTV OS's, so part of it is also DRMs capabilities of Firefox OS. Are these Firefox OS forks with proprietary additions, e.g. Panasonic TVs? I suppose that netflix is available on Panasonic TVs running firefoxOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox OS builds on open standards and any other things like DRM support is in hands of manufacturer who wants to build on Firefox OS.

E.g. Panasonic builds on Firefox OS and adds their own features like DRM support, specifically PlayReady in their HTML5 v2.0 SDK. Source [developer page](https://developer.vieraconnect.com/).